# Inrersect and minus operations

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem in set operations in Mysql. I want to execeute the following code to get net profit.

```
select sum(trnscn_income_amount) from transactions2

minus

select sum(trnscn_expense_amount) from transactions1;
```

but the minus is not becoming blue and thus it is giving a syntax error just after minus.

Is minus operation has to be done in different way ?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support the `MINUS` set operator.

But even if it did, it doesn't seem to make much sense in that query. That query is basically saying return a row, unless a certain condition is met.

If you want to return the difference between the values returned by the two queries, just subtract them, for example:

```
SELECT i.tot_income - e.tot_expense 
  FROM (SELECT SUM(trnscn_income_amount) AS tot_income FROM transactions2) i
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(trnscn_expense_amount) AS tot_expense FROM transactions1) e
```

But that's fundamentally different from the `MINUS` set operator. If what you want is an operation like the `MINUS` set operator (available in other relational databases), you can emulate that in MySQL with a classic "anti-join" pattern: a left join to return all rows from the left side, along with matching rows from the right side, and then filter out all rows that had a match, leaving rows from the left side that didn't have a match. But I don't think this is really what you want to do.

This query is equivalent to the original query if the `MINUS` set operator was supported in MySQL:

```
SELECT i.tot_income
  FROM (SELECT SUM(trnscn_income_amount) AS tot_income FROM transactions2) i
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT SUM(trnscn_expense_amount) AS tot_expense FROM transactions1) e 
    ON e.tot_expense = i.tot_income
 WHERE e.tot_expense IS NULL
```